# Custom Progress Bar in Browser

Tags: jquery, html, css

I’ve seen that some sites can override the native loading progress bar (in address bar) with their custom progress bar. Eg. http://www.codegent.com

At first I suspect it’s done with jQuery, but it shouldn’t affect the state of browser.

What is the method they use to get this type of effect?

Comment: here is what you are saying:http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/

Comment: and this:http://jquery-plugins.net/pace-automatic-page-load-progress-bar

Comment: @EhsanSajjad thanks! You should leave it as answer so I can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you are saying, there are many plugins available that you can use for that purpose.

Here are few links:

http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/

http://jquery-plugins.net/pace-automatic-page-load-progress-bar